# Excel list of students who is a transfer student, who's a retainee and who isn't in system

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

In my list in excel, I have a group of students as follows, for an example list. I cut it down to only show the necessary data.

- Student 1     N/A
- Student 1     N/A
- Student 1     N/A
- Student 1     Retained
- Student 2     Retained
- Student 2     Transferred
- Student 2     Retained
- Student 3     Retained
- Student 3     Retained
- Student 4     N/A
- Student 4     N/A

I want it to show that Student 2 was a transfer student period, while Students 1 and 3 are Retained Students, and student 4 is not in the system due to being N/A.

Thank you in advance, everyone.

Comment: Pardon me, what is your question?

Comment: Do you want the **last matched** status for each student ??

Comment: Sorry, newacc2240. I wanted to compile a list and show where each student was either a retainee or transfer student in a particular school. It also doesn't matter what their latest matched status was either, Gary's Student. I just wanted to know if the student was a transfer or retainee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

In cell E2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=INDEX({"Transferred","Retained","N/A"},MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,D2,$B$2:$B$12,{"Transferred","Retained","N/A"})>0,),0))
```

Adjust for your actual data

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. Sorry if it was an issue!